# Is the Harbin Y-11 a fully indigenous Chinese design?

Tags: aircraft-design

One book characterized the [Harbin Y-11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harbin_Y-11) as a "successor" aircraft to a design based on the [Antonov An-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonov_An-2), however, it looks completely different than the An-2, which is a single-engine aircraft. Is the Harbin Y-11 a fully indigenous Chinese design with no significant elements copied from some other aircraft?

Comment: It is probably just saying that the Y-11 was the new aircraft to fill the role previously covered by designs like the An-2. Sort of looks like a Twin Otter.

Comment: It has a overhead wing with a spar -> many skydiving planes have that as well

Comment: While it is possible that the designer lived in a vacuum and took no outside influences into his design, it uses several design elements shown in several other aircraft of that era, designed with the same roles in mind. What do you mean when you say "indigenous"... if you mean what I would, I would say no.

Comment: @CGCampbell By an independent design I mean using your own plans and drawings, not reversed drawings based on calipered measurements of existing aircraft. In other words if the measurements are exactly the same as some other aircraft that would be a "copy". If the measurements of the component are unique, then it is an independent design.

Answer (score 1):

Though Harbin Aircraft Manufacturing Corporation (HAMC) said Y-11 is a fully indigenous design, no other direct evidences prove/reject what it says. However, some indirect evidence shall be considered:

1) Except Y11, the only brand new design from HAMC is Z15 in 2008(Coperation with Airbus), other designs from HAMC are either authorised production or modification from existed model.

2) Y11 was designed in the period of the [Cultural Revolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultural_Revolution). There is insufficient engineers and research process is often influenced by political movement. However, Y-11 started first flight 8 months after the requirement is issued.

Based on the evidences i dont think it is a fully indigenous Chinese design, as they dont have experience for fully indigenous design in such a short period.

Comment: pure speculation. China had a lot of smart people, many of them trained abroad. HAMC didn't need to design many aircraft as they produced the Y-11 (and later the Y-12) exclusively for decades. That's how things work in a communist country. Saying the fact they only produced that one model proves they didn't design it is like saying Lada couldn't have designed their car in the 1960s because they never designed another until the mid 1980s...

Answer (score 0):

After some research it appears the Y-11 is an independent design based on the Soviet [Antonov An-28](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonov_An-28) with various significant modifications. The design appears to be a scaled down version of the An-28. Certain elements such as the undercarriage and wing supports are identical.

Comment: parallel evolution would account for that easily. The Twin Otter is also very similar in design, and there are others. The configuration is a logical one given the requirements all those aircraft were designed to.